# spring websocket in cluster server, how to save WebSocketSession when deploying one server

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

Here is a implementation of spring-websocket:

```
@Component
public class SystemWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("connect to the websocket success......");
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Server:connected OK!"));
    }
    // omit other method
}
```

I found the WebSocketSession is not a **Serializable** interface. I can't save it to shared repository(like redis...).
I have a tomcat cluster, the WebSocketSession may be in one of them. I need to deploy(restart some servers and keep other alive) if code changed.

Is it the only way to communicate with front-end by the WebSocketSession Object?
If so, what if I restart the server, will client lose the connection?

Comment: But losing web-socket connection is not something unusual for client. Client should reconnect automatically.

Comment: Using full feature broker should be better.